# passing a text file into an int or array using c#

Tags: c#, parsing, text-files

I am reasonably new to C# programming I took it up in the past week and I am having issues connecting two parts of my program together. Where I stand I have it reading information from a text file and then I need to pass the information into ints for the main part of the program to use and run its functions with.  Basically the text file will look something like this

30 3 5

100 7 16

etc.... 
each set of numbers is in groups of 3s just to clarify if I didn't explain it well enough.

but with each group of numbers I need them set up where I can pass to my ints X Y and Z that are declared after the text file is ran so if needed. The only thought that I have had at the moment is pass them into an array and call the ints  (I can do int x = arr[1]; if I coded that right) that way but I have had no luck getting them into the array let alone calling them individually.

I am more then open to hearing other options but could someone please help and explain how it is done in the sections of code I would like to understand what is happening at each step.

Comment: edit and add code you've come so far

Comment: I would use a List<int> for each row, then add those rows to a List<List<int>>.  You'll have to parse each row and convert the string values into int before adding them to the list.

Comment: Idle is right: The word is __parse__! You can ReadAllLines and the Split(' ')..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
static int[] parse(string st)//let st be "13 12 20"
{
    int[] a = new int[3];
    a[0] = int.Parse(st.Substring(0, st.IndexOf(' ')));//this will return 13, indexof means where is the space, substring take a portion from the sting
    st = st.Remove(0, st.IndexOf(' ') + 1);//now remove the first number so we can get the second, st will be "12 20"
    a[1] = int.Parse(st.Substring(0, st.IndexOf(' ')));//second number
    st = st.Remove(0, st.IndexOf(' ') + 1);//st="20"
    a[2] = int.Parse(st);//all we have is the last number so all string is needed(no substring)
    return a;
}
```

this method parse the string and get three ints from it and stores them in an array, then return this array. we shall use it to parse the lines of the text file like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader f = new StreamReader("test.txt");//the file
    int x, y, z;
    while (!f.EndOfStream)//stop when we reach the end of the file
    {
        int[] a = parse(f.ReadLine());//read a line from the text file and parse it to an integer array(using parse which we defined)
        x = a[0];//get x
        y = a[1];//get y
        z = a[2];//get z
        //do what you want with x and y and z here I'll just print them
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", x, y, z);
    }
    f.Close();          //close the file when finished  
}
```

Comment: Is the first part of this reading the text file and pasting it into an array while setting x y and z? and for the second part I am not really sure what all of that does would you mind explain it?

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you have any questions, I'll answer them

Comment: I have read though the code and ran it but I get an error when I try to run it. I want to understand both aspects of it but I get really cloudy when I reach the a[0] = int.Parse(st.Substring(0, st.IndexOf(' '))); section of the code. This is the error that is returned by the way. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Length cannot be less than zero.

Comment: @MadHatter are there long integers in your text file ? a long won't parse by int.parse but by long.parse , if you have that I'll edit my answer.
ofcourse long means numbers bigger than 2^32 -1 or smaller than -2^32

Comment: The longest ints that I had set up for the tests were no more then 3 digits and the most I believe that are going to be tested are 4 digits and my first test run to see if I got the code working correctly was using the 13 12 20 starting like that then I swapped them to each their own line

Comment: @MadHatter I followed the format you provided, you didn't tell me you want them on different lines, ofcourse this make difference

Comment: I tried both formats for numbers and this is me trying to learn c# for the first time I have a decent amount of experience in Java but, I took up c# about a week ago for something new to do to keep my mind active and try to buff my resume if I was decent with it. The entire section of code I added to my question was written by me it was a modified fizzbuzz program that could accept any number instead of the static ones the original program stated.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong it took a few hour break and then it dawned on me that Visual Studio had open TextFile1 and the file that had the numbers and was in the correct folder was textfile1 thank you for all of the help I managed to complete my program

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way. However you need to work on it to make more suitable according to your needs:
I can admit that you need to do more error handling in my below code e.g in `Convert.ToInt32`section

```
           public void XYZFile()
           {
                List<XYZ> xyzList = new List<XYZ>();
                string[] xyzFileContant = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/XYZ.txt"));
                //int lineCount = xyzFileContant.Length;
                foreach (string cont in xyzFileContant)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cont))
                    {
                        string[] contSplit = cont.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        xyzList.Add(new XYZ
                                            {
                                                X = Convert.ToInt32(contSplit[0]),
                                                Y = Convert.ToInt32(contSplit[1]),
                                                Z = Convert.ToInt32(contSplit[2])
                                            }
                            );
                    }
                }
            }



    public class XYZ
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int Z { get; set; }
    }
```

So, let me know if that helps you.

Comment: I just want to ask some qestions on specific lines since I haven't seen some of these before.     

List<XYZ> xyzList = new List<XYZ>(); - is this line creating a list? 

    cont  - is this continue or count? I haven't seen this used before either 

     string[] contSplit = cont.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); this looks like it is creating an array named string and removing all spaces from the entries is that correct?

X = Convert.ToInt32(contSplit[0]), - is this splitting the array and assigning a value to x after converting it to an int?

Comment: public int X { get; set; } - is this line allowing me to grab x and use it further into the program?

Comment: List<XYZ> is collection of XYZ class and XYZ class has member X, Y and Z to hold said value say X=30, Y=3, Z=5.  
`cont` is just a string type variable.  
`string[] contSplit = cont.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`-> Yes I am splitting each line of the text file and storing it in string array. so it will have values like contSplit[0] = "30",contSplit[1]="3" and contSplit[2]="5"

Comment: Thank you for all of the help the code defiantly makes more sense now and it should help me finish my project.

Comment: @Mad Hatter
Was this a real question or a request to solve your homework? (just curious)

Comment: no I have the largest part of my project done it was added that I needed to read a text file and parse it on for integers when the original assignment was to pull it from a keyboard input. I found out how to use the stream reader with the system.IO but I was having issues putting the stream into an array and calling it into the latter part of the program